# Replacing an arbitrary function of a variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

If I do something like

```
1/Sqrt[x] /. {Sqrt[x] -> a}
```

it does not lead to an expected result, but can be fixed with

```
1/Sqrt[x] /. {Sqrt[x] -> a, 1/Sqrt[x] -> 1/a}
```

I am wondering if, for given `g[x]` and `h[x]`, there exists a general way of replacing any `f[g[x]]` with `f[h[x]]`?

Comment: You have to see `FullForm` of your expression to write a working replacement rule.

Comment: Sometimes results are better replacing a single variable rather than an expression. `1/Sqrt[x] /. {x -> a^2} // PowerExpand`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/4999 -- the question at the end seems to have no relation to the implicit question in the beginning examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{Sqrt[x], 1/Sqrt[x]} // FullForm
```

> List[Power[x,Rational[1,2]],Power[x,Rational[-1,2]]]

Try:

```
rule = Power[x, Rational[g_, 2]] -> a^Sign[g]
{Sqrt[x], 1/Sqrt[x]} /. rule
```

> {a, 1/a}

---

For your other query:

```
f[g[x]] /. g -> h
```

> f[h[x]]

Comment: Thank you. Note that, strictly speaking, my second question is the generalization of the first one, yet I cannot do smth like `Sqrt -> ...` (say, for replacing `Sqrt[x]` with some constant `a`)

Comment: `Sqrt` gets translated as above using `Fullform`. Replacements work mechanically and don't interpret user's intention so a literal rule is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Extended comment

```
1/Sqrt[x] // FullForm
```

> [image: ff]

The following works

```
expr = 1/Sqrt[x];
Numerator[expr]/(Denominator[expr] /. Sqrt[x] -> a)
```

> [image: 1/a]

The general replacement an be done as follows:

```
fun = f[g[x]] + D[f[g[x]], x]
fun /. g -> Function[{x}, a^2 h[x]]
```

> [image: 1]
> [image: 2]